# "Must declare the scalar variable" error

Tags: sql-server

Hello everyone I'm a beginner in sql server.

I declared a variable like this,

```
DECLARE @ColumnName INT
```

and tried initializing it.

```
SET @ColumnName = 0;
```

But it is giving the error

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@ColumnName".
```

Comment: Please show us the **complete** script! Do you e.g. have a `GO` between the declaration and the assignment?

Comment: Try executing both the statements.I mean declare and SET stmt together.

Comment: Are you executing this from front-end? @user3387567

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute both statements at the same time. If you execute them individually, you will get the error message you describe.

```
DECLARE @ColumnName INT;
SET @ColumnName = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute both statements at a time.

```
DECLARE @ColumnName INT
SET @ColumnName = 0;
```